# Park Unpark to developing custom blocking queue

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, wait, notify

In usual example of Java concurrent system of producer-consumer, blocking queue is developed using `wait()` / `notify()` method. But it is said that `park()` / `unpark()` method of `LockSupport` should be used instead of these.

I could not get any tutorial or example of it.

Can anyone give such example using park-unpark?

Comment: The JDK has a builtin `BlockingQueue`, why not use that?

Comment: The JDK also has [Sample Usage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) right at the `LockSupport` page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to provide functionality which is the same or similar to a built in the class, the best example is that built in class.

While [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java) uses park/unpark indirectly, it uses Locks and Conditions to perform the actions it needs.